# How do I pipe my raw keystrokes through a command before sending it through ssh to remote systems

Tags: bash, maildir

To better specify my question, I have decided that I want every keystroke to be piped to a package called safecat which uses the maildir algorithm, which is in turn delivering it's output to a remote machine via ssh.

I just feel like when i do mess up, which i will, it would be really cool have that record of exactly what i did on that particular machine to result in such hilarious catastrophe.

If there is a totally different means to achieve the same result, I'm not fussed, but from what i can tell the final keystrokes are difficult to recover.

Comment: Consider looking at the "script" command, which records terminal sessions.

Comment: Also consider changing you title to something like "How do I pipe my raw keystrokes through a command before sending it through ssh to remote systems"

Comment: it's an all new low for me but I'm going to go ahead and cut and paste that. thanks.

Comment: A quick search turned up several keyloggers for Linux. I am not going to recommend any particular package but one of the first hits that did not require root privileges is this [simple keylogger](https://github.com/GiacomoLaw/Keylogger). You will have to modify to pipe to safecat.

Comment: Welcome to the wacky world of Unix. If you ever get the feeling that it seems like things are coherent, but you can't quite see the pattern, just know: people break the pattern all the time. Your intuition isn't wrong, but it isn't right, either. But the power is so much fun.

Comment: If you want a more exotic solution, have you considered making `~/.bash_history` a named pipe and having safecat read from the pipe? And, for the comment from @HackSaw, `script` may be too noisy. For a simple example, `ps -fe` is one line with six characters but it produced 887 lines of output on one of my systems.

Comment: so when one refers to stdin and stdout, is this system wide or only for that terminal? because of course it's not just the keystrokes i want to make a remote synchronous record of, its all the processes running prior to the crash or performance reduction occurs

Comment: stdin and stdout are specific to the process, such as the shell.

Comment: Recording *everything* that is going on in a system would produce simply astonishing amounts of data, rendering it practically impossible to analyze. And you generally don't need all that, just whatever is happening where you are right now. Unix programs don't particularly interact with each other unless someone has made them do this. Those programs won't be doing things to your work at all, unless something is very weird.

Comment: A lot of what's happening on the system will be recorded in the log files (typically in /var/log). Very useful to be conversant with those.

Comment: If you want to get an idea of what a particular process is doing, take a look at "strace", (system call trace) and try it on something. Then if you really want to drink from the firehose, take a look at "ltrace" (library call trace).

Comment: ok thanks. I was thinking of simply assigning multiple commands to the same hot keys ive assigned to the command that opens up a new terminal, really just a bash script that opens up the ssh connection and so forth, i think i need to re watch the tut video on the linux file system again, rank directories in priority like /var/log

Comment: I dont really want **all**  the data to be transferred, I just know whatever happens its always my fault, so just the keystrokes for the past say 24 hrs is the prize for me, i buy old computers that are under 100 USD and do regular back ups, i just want to learn what i did each time

Comment: This is an old [link](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-audit-all-commands-run-on-oel-56-using-auditd/) but I think you're looking for auditd for a robust and complete solution. Be prepared to very large log files.

Comment: thanks ill go through the man page now, there are a lot of candidates for what I'm trying to set up, a good portion of it isn't time sensitive or even dependent, i will be making and ruining a VM over and over basically, i think the success of the keystroke record part i refer to in this question,(which is of course very time sensitive)  is going to heavily rely on how synchronized the remote connection is. but that's what's so frustrating because i know the final seconds of the machine are crucial forensically speaking because i know I'm the cause lol

Comment: on bullseye, I've been encountering a persistent issue conducting file compression from the command line but ok no worries once i try it and know how much how fast i can work with that

Comment: right ok i see what you mean it has the audisp-remote plugin so its going to be a plus if that element is done via the one package

Answer (score 0):

In finding the solution to the missing entries in the bash history file due to having multiple terminals open on this site which i will [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398904/how-can-i-sync-all-terminal-sessions-to-one-history-file) when i find it again, but it was to add the following line to the .bashrc file:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n"
```

So I am thinking that appending a command to the list in green that appends a log file and delivers it via scp to a remote machine with an ssh connection with the local *should* work if my presumption is true, so the keystrokes can be inferred if indeed a completely synchronous appending process occurs throughout your LAN.